# In databases (NOT only relational), what exactly is a "row" vs. a "column"

Tags: database, nosql

I see most of the new NoSQL database vendors describing their particular data model using the age-old row-column vocabulary. This is causing me a lot of confusion.

My question is: In the new world where NoSQL databases are no longer second-class citizens to relational / SQL databases, can someone assist with precise universally applicable definitions of a "row" vs. a "column".

(By the way, I am not looking for differences between row-oriented and column-oriented databases)

Here is an example:

Let us assume a situation where you are told that you will be handed ball-shaped objects one by one, every 0.01 seconds. Each ball is identified by a unique number (an integer). You are told that these balls can change color. Assume that multi-colored balls are not a possibility. For any given measurement the ball you are given will have a color identified by a color hex code.

You are asked to tabulate the data in a row-column format.

You do not know how many total unique balls there are. (the number of balls may turn out to much less than the number of possible colors. Alternatively, the number of colors may turn out to be much less than the number of balls)

You need to tabulate the data in a time-series format. Each measurement will have:
A Timestamp
The identity of the object (positive integer)
The identity of the color.(hex code)

How would you decide whether the measurements are grouped vertically or horizontally?. Aren't there multiple ways of representing the data in a row-column format without being "wrong"?

Here is one way of tabulating the data:

Time-stamp   |    Ball    |  Color Code

0.02              344       #3452b3

0.03        34556       #001000

0.03        00007       #766cc3

In the above case, each measurement is a row (horizontal)

Here is another way to tablulate the same data:

Time-stamp  0.02    |   0.03    |   0.04

Ball        344 |   34556   |   00007

Color Code  #3452b3 |   #001000 |   #766cc3

I have re-represented the same data but I found it more intuitive to keep all data for each measurement grouped vertically. 
Is that inherently wrong? 
Is the vertical column in my 2nd representation actually a "horizontal row" in nosql (or relational) data-modeling speak?

I understand that the actual physical model on how a database stores its data on disk, is independent of the data model representation in their documentation. If that last statement is correct, how do they (the authors of the database model documentation) decide what is to be placed horizontally and what is to be placed vertically in their data diagrams?

Answer (score 3):

A row or a record is a horizontal form of data representing a single piece of related data.

A column or a field is a vertical form of data whic represents one specific characteristic of the data.

For instance, take the following table:

```
UID | Name
----+--------
  1 | "Harry"
  2 | "Sarah"
```

UID and name are two separate fields describing the data whereas each horizontal row is an instance of such data.

Under your example, the meaning of a row/column changes; **however**, *it is* ***not*** *a change in what the terms look like.*

In English, a row will always be horizontal, a column will always be vertical, but the jobs associated with them will change depending on how the data is represented.

There is such thing as an Object Database which has no concept of rows and columns (ie. data is not represented in a tabulated form); instead, data is represented as separate entities.

In ODB's, a class is similiar to a table, and an object or instance is like a record. The object properties are the fields that describe such data.

### Summary

1. In a **relational database**, data is represented in tables. Records are instances of data, fields describe the data.
2. A row is always horizontal while a column is always vertical (English is English; just because the terms are used in databases doesn't mean their representation changes).
3. In databases that do not use sql, data may be represented in other formats. For instance,
4. In object databases, a class defines the data structure, an object is a representation of each instance of data, and a property describes each individual characteristic of the data.
5. Rows and columns only have meaning in tabular data. Object Databases, for instance, do not represent the data in tabular form.
6. There are **many** kinds of databases; relational databases are the *most common*.

Comment: What if the set of information is such that the "data" and the "characteristic" can swap roles depending on the query / business use case.

Comment: @snaik Elaborate please

Comment: revised question with example. Thanks for your time and attention. Much appreciated.

Comment: @snaik the fact that there are many ways to model the information in your example is independent of the rules of [relational modeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) where "rows" take a [specific form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) in order to map to [relational algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) which is what allows RDBMS's to generically manipulate your data.

Comment: @gordy but most "nosql" databases are not relational. So are we using rules of relational modeling in our new expanded world that includes nosql databases?

Comment: @snaik when you ask "in databases" I assume that you mean "in relational databases" - there are no rules that would encompass modeling techniques applicable to relational and non-relational. In your question, the 2nd example would most certainly be wrong if you were going for a relational model, but if you are not then there is no wrong - you can do whatever works